# Unrecognized extension in ADLS which is written from a dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Can someone please help, the issue is:
I have a database feom that i am writing data to adls gen2 with a dataflow by making some transformations, but the output patquet file is having weired data and

```
Error: sample.parquet file not rendered correctly and has unrecognized extension
```

How i can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to read a parquet file, which was copied from an SQL database to ADLS Gen 2 with some transformations in the data flow, I faced the same issue as shown below:

```
The file 'Data.parquet' may not render correctly as it contains an unrecognized extension.
```

[image]

As per [this](https://www.dremio.com/resources/guides/intro-apache-parquet/), Parquet is a binary-based (rather than text-based) file format optimized for computers, so Parquet files aren't directly readable by humans. That may be the reason for getting the error and the data with Unicode as above. So, if we want to view the data of a snappy.parquet file, read it in Databricks, use Parquet reading tools, or upload it to an online [Parquet viewer](https://www.tablab.app/view/parquet) as shown below:

[image]